# Drawing in gazebo ROS

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, gazebo, rviz

I am trying to simulate motion for a ur5e robotic arm. I am using the concept of Rodrigues rotation to get the orientation for the end effector. Is there any way to draw a line in gazebo or RViz from one point to another?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to draw arbitrary shapes in RViz is to use the [Marker Display](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker) you can draw shapes in specific locations with colors and different alpha elements.

If you want to interact with them you an step up to [interactive_markers](http://wiki.ros.org/interactive_markers)

I recommend getting more info from the [rviz Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials)